# React Native component not getting this.props.dispatch from Redux

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm setting up Redux with React Native for the first time in a simple app.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482274/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-dispatch-in-react-native) my setup with redux for React Native should be working, but when I tap the "swap currencies" button on the home screen of my app I get the error "this.props.dispatch is not an object". Why is my Home component not getting the dispatch prop?

(According to the [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-props-dispatch) the `connect()` function should get a default `mapDispatchToProps`, that is all I would like for now.)

Check out the code at [this repo](https://github.com/axelkennedal/CurrencyConverter/tree/redux). (Relevant files are App.js, app/components/Home.js, app/config/store, the reducers folder and actions folder)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass "this" to function. When you call your function handleSwapCurrency doesn't know about your context. All you need to do:

```
handleSwapCurrency = () => {
      console.log("pressed swap currency");
      this.props.dispatch(swapCurrency());
}
```

This allows you to use this of class, because arrow function doesn't have they own this. Also you can bind your function inside constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I'm so used to having access to 'this' in Java :)